# How do I extract the text from this div?

Tags: python, html

```
<div id="wordlist" style="display:none;">leave|river|what|try|just|because|cut|now|made|
```

I just want to get the words and here's the code that I used but it just gives me wordlist as the output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find("div", attrs={'id': 'wordlist'}).get('id')
print(text)
```

Comment: A list of words would be available with `text.text.split('|')`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should output just the text.

`text = soup.find("div", attrs={'id': 'wordlist'})`
`print(text.text)`

Comment: When I print out the text it doesn't print out anything

Comment: try removing the `.get('id')` from your code. I'm not sure what that is doing. The `.text` should work to output your text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `get('id')`.  Instead, just print `text` from the `soup.find` result.

```
result = soup.find("div", attrs={'id': 'wordlist'})
print(result.text)
```